# JPEG file not opening after creating it with Writefile Api (Ionic-Cordova)

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

**I am creating a JPEG image with writeFile Api.**
It is giving me success on this and creating an jpeg image in the directory.
But when I open that file manually by going into that directory it gives me error that
"Oops! Couldn't load this image"

```
this.file.writeFile(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory,"image.jpeg",blob,true).then(succ=>{
               console.log("File Write : ",succ)
},err=>{
             console.log("File Write Error : ",err)
})
```

How can I solve this **problem** or any one can guide me what is the other method to create an jpeg image in ionic.

Answer (score 0):

The third argument in your function seems to be empty.
you should pass the image blob to create it as a file.

You can create text file with empty value. But image file needs to have blob data.

```
this.file.writeFile(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory,"image.jpeg","",true)
```

Comment: In my actual code I am passing blob in the third argument but still I am getting the error.

We can pass blob or a string in the third argument.

It is also giving me the same error with CreateFile Api